# JAVA SOAP modification help request to change parameter names

Tags: java, soap

I created a web service and run a simple calculator program as below:

```
public void sumAndMultiply(int a, int b,
                           @WebParam(name = "joda", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> sum,
                           @WebParam(name = "ghatak", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> multiply) {
    sum.value = a + b;
    multiply.value = a * b;
}
```

}

For this, I send `<arg0>` and `<arg1>` for values a and b as:

```
<arg0> 4 </arg0>
<arg1> 5 </arg1>
```

what should I modify in the code to change the parameter name such that I need to send the request like:

```
<firstnumber>4</firstnumber>
<secondnumber>5</secondnumber>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@WebParam(name="")` in front of each input variable.

```
@WebMethod  
public void sumAndMultiply(@WebParam(name = "firstnumber") int a, 
                           @WebParam(name = "secondnumber") int b) {
// some stuff here

}
```

---

```
public void sumAndMultiplyAndReference
    (@WebParam(name = "firstnumber")int a,
     @WebParam(name = "firstnumber")int b,
     @WebParam(name = "referencenumber")int c
     @WebParam(name = "sum", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> sum,
     @WebParam(name = "multiply", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> multiply,
     @WebParam(name = "reference", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> reference){
    sum.value = a + b;
    multiply.value = a * b;
    reference.value = c;
}
```

---

```
public void sumAndMultiplyAndReference
    (@WebParam(name = "firstnumber", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN)int a,
     @WebParam(name = "firstnumber", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN)int b,
     @WebParam(name = "referencenumber", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN)int c
     @WebParam(name = "sum", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> sum,
     @WebParam(name = "multiply", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> multiply,
     @WebParam(name = "referencenumber", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> referencenumber){
    sum.value = a + b;
    multiply.value = a * b;
    referencenumber.value = c;
}
```

Comment: Dear Aleksey, what if I want a reference number in request and reply back the same reference number along with sum and multiply??

Comment: in your example: request paramter is "referenumber" and reply paramater is "reference". isn't it possible to reply with same parameter name: referencenumber?

Comment: it didn't worked...error as: the duplicity found in @WebParam.name attribute

Comment: sorry i didn't get you. I am getting error while i tried as your example "the duplicity found in @WebParam.name attribute"